# UNION query functionality and the query structure

Tags: mysql, sql, not-exists

What I'm trying to achieve is to insert values into a table if that value does not exist in 2 extra tables.

```
INSERT INTO visitor(
  visitor_username,
  email,
  PASSWORD
)
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
    'admin2000',
    'adminemail@mail.com',
    '123456'
) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT
    admin.admin_username,
    admin.email
FROM
    admin AS admin
WHERE
    admin.admin_username = 'admin2000' AND admin.email = 
'adminemail@mail.com'
UNION
SELECT
staff.staff_username,
staff.email
FROM
staff AS staff
WHERE
staff.staff_username = 'admin2000' AND staff.email = 
'adminemail@mail.com'
 )
LIMIT 1
```

In the WHERE NOT EXIST part when I only ask for *_username (example: admin_username or staff_username) it works well, but when I need to verify if the email exists too it does not work as intended.

Am I using WHERE NOT EXIST properly? if the username 'admin2000' and email 'adminemail@mail.com' exist on the table 'admin' and I'm trying to insert it into 'visitor' table it inserts it and it should not be doing that.

Comment: To me that query looks correct. Not entirely as I would write it (I would at least use two separate `not exists`, use `union all`, use `tmp` in the subqueries, instead of repeatingthe values, and omit `limit 1`), but I don't see why it wouldn't work this way... Unless there is one admin with the username 'admin2000', and another one with the email 'adminemail@mail.com'. In that case it wouldn't work. The two values have to be combined in one row if you write it like this.

Comment: it shouldnt insert (username 'admin2000' and email 'adminemail@mail.com') into the table 'visitor' because the email 'adminemail@mail.com' exist in the 'admin' table, the only thing that does not exist across the tables is the username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `AND` in the subqueries. It searches for rows that have that username AND that email. So if you have an admin called `admin2000`, but with a different e-mail address, that admin won't be returned by the subquery, and so the new row will be inserted.

Use `OR` instead of `AND`, and the the problem will be solved.

Comment: Silly me, how could I've not noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to be writing a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO visitor (visitor_username, email, PASSWORD)
    SELECT t.*
    FROM (SELECT 'admin2000' as visitor_username, 'adminemail@mail.com' as email, '123456' as PASSWORD
         ) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM admin a
                      WHERE a.visitor_username = t.visitor_username AND a.email = t.email
                     )
    UNION 
    SELECT s.staff_username, s.email, ? as password
    FROM staff s
    WHERE s.staff_username = 'admin2000' AND s.email = 
'adminemail@mail.com';
```

Note that the second subquery is missing a password, so there is an error.

This seems more concisely written using a single query:

```
INSERT INTO visitor (visitor_username, email, PASSWORD)
    SELECT t.*
    FROM (SELECT 'admin2000' as visitor_username, 'adminemail@mail.com' as email, '123456' as PASSWORD
         ) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM admin a
                      WHERE a.admin_username = t.visitor_username AND a.email = t.email
                     ) AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM staff s
                      WHERE s.staff_username = t.visitor_username AND s.email = t.email
                     );
```

Comment: it is required that the usernames and emails are unique across those 3 tables (I know its a bad desing for the database, and I've told them)

Comment: @Hexxul . . . That makes more sense (I misread your query).  Just use `NOT EXISTS` twice with `AND`.  This should have the best performance.